# ZPL Zebra Printer and Latin Extended-B char Issue

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, zebra-printers, zpl, zebra

I'm facing an Issue while trying to print some Latin Extended-B character in zebra printer

the code I use is :

```
^XA
^CI28

^CF0,30
^FD Thañk yòú fôr showing me : Ƌ ƀ Ƈ Ǝ  ě š č ř ž ý á í é 

^XZ
```

where `Ƌ ƀ Ƈ Ǝ` are Latin Extended-B character and `ě š č ř ž ý á í é`  aren't Extended-B

The Zebra printed result is :

[image: generated ZPL]

For Latin Extended-B char , here are the list of available char with thier encoding:

https://graphemica.com/blocks/latin-extended-b

Comment: Font-0 does not support many of the Latin-B characters.  The best approach is to download a font that does.  For example, Zebra supplies the Swiss 721 font that has much better character support.  See: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/printer-software/printer-fonts.html under FREE PRINTER FONT PACKAGES.